# See what images were uploaded to imgur using my app ClientID?

Tags: imgur

I'm using the https://api.imgur.com/3/image to upload images from JavaScript without **oauth**.
Is it possible to see what images were uploaded recently using my `Client-ID`?

Comment: sorry, but seems that the image model exposed by the endpoint doesn't provide informations about the client ==> http://api.imgur.com/models/image

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately it's not directly possible but I think the following approach will give good results: use the following endpoint to retrieve all your associated images:

https://api.imgur.com/3/account/{username}/images

Or the following for account submitted images:

https://api.imgur.com/3/account/{username}/submissions/

For the Username you can use 'me' and you need to send the Client-ID using the correct header:

'Authorization: Client-ID YOUR_CLIENT_ID'

This will return all the images uploaded from the account and you need to filter them yourself.

If you are uploading them to a gallery and want to know only these you can set the time window in the request ( week, day, etc.)